# R function for creating uneven groups based on uneven dates

Tags: r, date, dplyr, grouping

I am trying to find an R function that can index groups iteratively, given a set of unevenly spaced dates, uneven group sizes, and by grouped cases. Here are example data:

```
> h
# A tibble: 20 x 2
      ID date      
   <int> <date>    
 1     1 2021-01-07
 2     1 2021-01-11
 3     1 2021-01-15
 4     1 2021-01-16
 5     1 2021-01-21
 6     1 2021-01-26
 7     1 2021-02-04
 8     1 2021-02-08
 9     1 2021-02-13
10     1 2021-02-20
11     1 2021-02-23
12     1 2021-02-27
13     2 2021-01-05
14     2 2021-01-11
15     2 2021-02-02
16     2 2021-02-08
17     2 2021-02-08
18     2 2021-02-14
19     2 2021-02-17
20     2 2021-02-21
```

For each unique `ID`, I want to find the first date (chronologically) and create a group (i.e., `group==1`) for that case and any other rows within 7 days. For the next date *after* 7 days, create a second group (i.e., `group==2`) for that case and any others within the next 7 days. Note: the next date is not necessarily exactly 7 days after the initial date. Repeat this process for the remaining remaining cases to get the desired output:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
      ID date       group
   <int> <date>     <dbl>
 1     1 2021-01-07     1
 2     1 2021-01-11     1
 3     1 2021-01-15     2
 4     1 2021-01-16     2
 5     1 2021-01-21     2
 6     1 2021-01-26     3
 7     1 2021-02-04     4
 8     1 2021-02-08     4
 9     1 2021-02-13     5
10     1 2021-02-20     5
11     1 2021-02-23     6
12     1 2021-02-27     6
13     2 2021-01-05     1
14     2 2021-01-11     1
15     2 2021-02-02     2
16     2 2021-02-08     2
17     2 2021-02-08     2
18     2 2021-02-14     3
19     2 2021-02-17     3
20     2 2021-02-21     3
```

Using a rolling window function of 7 days will **not** work, as far as I can tell, as it will group the cases incorrectly. But I am wondering if a sort of *custom* rolling window function could be used? I would prefer a solution using `dplyr`, but other options would also work. Any help here is appreciated.

```
> dput(h)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), date = structure(c(18634, 
18638, 18642, 18643, 18648, 18653, 18662, 18666, 18671, 18678, 
18681, 18685, 18632, 18638, 18660, 18666, 18666, 18672, 18675, 
18679), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function date1 which given the first date of the group of the prior row's point and the current row's date returns the date of the start of the current group -- that must be one of the two arguments.  Then grouping by ID use Reduce to apply that to the dates in each ID and convert the result to factor and then to integer.

```
library(dplyr)

date1 <- function(prev, x) if (x > prev + 7) x else prev
h %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(group = as.integer(factor(Reduce(date1, date, acc = TRUE)))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
      ID date       group
   <int> <date>     <dbl>
 1     1 2021-01-07     1
 2     1 2021-01-11     1
 3     1 2021-01-15     2
 4     1 2021-01-16     2
 5     1 2021-01-21     2
 6     1 2021-01-26     3
 7     1 2021-02-04     4
 8     1 2021-02-08     4
 9     1 2021-02-13     5
10     1 2021-02-20     5
11     1 2021-02-23     6
12     1 2021-02-27     6
13     2 2021-01-05     1
14     2 2021-01-11     1
15     2 2021-02-02     2
16     2 2021-02-08     2
17     2 2021-02-08     2
18     2 2021-02-14     3
19     2 2021-02-17     3
20     2 2021-02-21     3
```

Comment: Excellent! This works perfectly on the example data and my other test data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For each ID group, create `group` as a vector of NAs. While some `group` elements are still NA, take the first date value where `group` is NA and add 0 and 7 days to it to make a range of dates. For any rows where `date` is in the calculated date range, set elements of group to 1 more than the current max value of `group` (or 0 if group is still all NA).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[order(ID, date), {
     group <- rep(NA_real_, .N)
     while(any(is.na(group))){
       group_range <- first(date[is.na(group)]) + c(0, 7)
       group[date %between% group_range] <- 1 + max(fcoalesce(group, 0)) 
     }
     list(date, group) 
   }, by = ID]

# ID       date group
# 1:  1 2021-01-07     1
# 2:  1 2021-01-11     1
# 3:  1 2021-01-15     2
# 4:  1 2021-01-16     2
# 5:  1 2021-01-21     2
# 6:  1 2021-01-26     3
# 7:  1 2021-02-04     4
# 8:  1 2021-02-08     4
# 9:  1 2021-02-13     5
# 10:  1 2021-02-20     5
# 11:  1 2021-02-23     6
# 12:  1 2021-02-27     6
# 13:  2 2021-01-05     1
# 14:  2 2021-01-11     1
# 15:  2 2021-02-02     2
# 16:  2 2021-02-08     2
# 17:  2 2021-02-08     2
# 18:  2 2021-02-14     3
# 19:  2 2021-02-17     3
# 20:  2 2021-02-21     3
```

Here's another version where I try to limit the computations. No idea if it's actually faster

```
df[order(ID, date), {
     group <- rep(NA_integer_, .N)
     i <- 1L
     g <- 1L
     while(i <= .N){
       group_range <- date[i] + c(0, 7)
       chg <- date %between% group_range
       group[chg] <- g
       g <- g + 1L
       i <- i + sum(chg)
     }
     list(date, group) 
   }, by = ID]
```